# How do I check if pieces are put together in Android puzzle game?

Tags: android, viewflipper, imageswitcher, libpuzzle

I have 4 pieces initially.

[image: k]

A child must put them in this correct order: heart, yellow star, green star, grey star.

I suspect i can create some kind of container for every piece where they are drag-and-dropped:
[image: ii]

I implemented drag-drop, but how to implement 'containers'? What are they?
in the expert tab in studio i see image switcher, view flipper, view animator, view switcher.

What do I do?

At this point I don't need to show the source code, as I need someone to point in general direction.

Answer (score 1):

Container should be a child of the class [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), because that class allows you to add `View` objects to it. In your case that object is an image. The most basic three are `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`. Any one of these three will solve your problem.